# CreatedDate in ComplexFilterPart for AutomationInstance ObjectType

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, xml

Is it possible to include a 'CreatedDate' complex filter for ObjectType 'AutomationInstance' so only the latest runs are returned?

If I just to a simple filter for the 'ProgramID' it returns every run, which could work but seems bloated (~150KB per call).

Here is my 'AutomationInstance' call with a simple filter:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>AutomationInstance</ObjectType>
                <Properties>Name</Properties>
                <Properties>Status</Properties>
                <Properties>ProgramID</Properties>
                <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
                <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                    <Property>ProgramID</Property>
                    <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                    <Value>123-456-789</Value>
                </Filter>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Which returns a list of runs that looks like this:

```
            <Results xsi:type="AutomationInstance">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <CreatedDate>2023-04-01T12:01:01.05</CreatedDate>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <Name>Some Automation Job</Name>
                <IsActive>false</IsActive>
                <Status>1</Status>
                <AutomationID>123-456-789</AutomationID>
                <StatusMessage>Complete</StatusMessage>
            </Results>
```

However if I modify the above slightly to add in a complex filter:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>AutomationInstance</ObjectType>
                <Properties>Name</Properties>
                <Properties>Status</Properties>
                <Properties>ProgramID</Properties>
                <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
                <Filter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ComplexFilterPart">
                    <LeftOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                        <Property>CreatedDate</Property>
                        <SimpleOperator>between</SimpleOperator>
                        <DateValue>2023-12-16T21:00:00.000-08:00</DateValue>
                        <DateValue>2024-01-02T21:59:59.999-07:00</DateValue>
                    </LeftOperand>
                    <LogicalOperator>AND</LogicalOperator>
                    <RightOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                        <Property>ProgramID</Property>
                        <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                        <Value>123-456-789</Value>
                    </RightOperand>
                </Filter>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the error I get:

```
            <Results>
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <PartnerProperties>
                    <Name>ErrorMessage</Name>
                    <Value>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</Value>
                </PartnerProperties>
                <PartnerProperties>
                    <Name>ErrorStackTrace</Name>
                    <Value>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</Value>
                </PartnerProperties>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
            </Results>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rather use the new Automation Instance Data View. You could filter the sql based on the `automationinstanceendtime_utc` [https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_automation_instance.htm&type=5](https://Automation%20Instance%20Data%20View)

Comment: Unfortunately that data view has a 24 hour delay.